# How to add to object array pointer c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, object

I'm trying to add an object to an object array passed as an argument. Specifically, I have an array of buttons and I am adding a back button to the button array. How can I correctly do this? When I try the code below I get some weird glitches with the buttons passed from the original pointer array.

```
int createMenu(Button buttons[], int size)
{
    //Stuff here
}

int menu(Button buttons[], int size, bool back)
{
    Button * newButtons[size + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        *newButtons[i] = buttons[i];
    Button back(25, 19, "Back"); //Creates back button object
    *newButtons[0] = back;
    return createMenu(*newButtons, size + 1);
    //Makes menu with the back button
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to use arrays? In general avoid them and use vectors.

Comment: I never looked in to them. Would they be more or less memory-heavy? I am running this on a device with 3MB of RAM.

Comment: Yes, they would consume more memory than arrays. Probably in your situation it makes sense to use Arrays I guess.

Comment: Show the declaration of `createMenu`

Comment: This code dereferences an uninitialized pointer (when you wrote `*newButtons[i]`) . Also you never do anything with `newButtons` once you set it up.

Comment: BTW arrays must have size known at compile-time. `Button *newButtons[size+1];` is illegal (although some compilers offer this as an extension). Also, it is not possible to resize them at runtime.

Comment: @Anon : why does it make sense? It will consume a few bytes more, does it has any impact nowadays with GB of RAM? Makes no sense imho.

Comment: @galinette, he is using 3MB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop you reference buttons[size], which is ouside of its bounds. You also dereference members of newButtons without initializing them. And you try to pass `createMenu` an array of pointers, when it expects an array of buttons. Should be something like this:

```
int menu(Button buttons[], int size, bool back)
{
    Button * newButtons = new Button[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        newButtons[i + 1] = buttons[i];
    newButtons[0] = Button(25, 19, "Back");
    int result = createMenu(newButtons, size + 1);
    delete [] newButtons;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `delete newButtons;` should be `delete [] newButtons;`

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here's how it would look if you were using vectors:

```
int menu( std::vector<Button> buttons )
{
    buttons.push_back( Button(25, 19, "Back") );
    return createMenu( buttons );
}
```

If the button really needs to be pushed at the front then there are various options (e.g. actually push it at the front; or use a deque instead of a vector).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are using Button*, so pass address of the Button object.

```
int menu(Button buttons[], int size, bool back)
{

    Button ** newButtons = new Button*[size + 1];
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        newButtons[i] = &buttons[i];
    Button * back = new Button(9,11,"fdf"); //Creates back button object
    newButtons[0] = back;

    //Makes menu with the back button
createMenu(*newButtons, size+1);
}

void createMenu(Button buttons[], int size)
{
    (buttons[0]).foo();

    //Stuff here
}
```

Also, you are using the same variable name "back" both as bool and as object of Button class. Change that.

Comment: I still get strange results with this. Maybe it's something related to my compiler.

Comment: This stores the address of a local variable

Comment: @MattMcNabb, thanks for that! That was unforgivable.

Comment: I still don't get the expected results. But it looks like your answer should work.

Comment: Are you able to compile now? What is the error you get?

Comment: It compiles. Just when I access the objects of the array (using ->) something isn't communicating correctly; the buttons don't respond.

Comment: @RandomPerson323, I updated my answer. I tried with a dummy class I wrote and I get the expected answer. This should work.

Comment: As currently showing, this still only exposes the first button to `createMenu` - presumably OP wants `createMenu` to be able to see all buttons